# Get header text of column from SysHeader32

Tags: c#, pinvoke, unmanaged, syslistview32

I'm working on an C# application that have to capture data from other appication (unmanaged).

This another application has many SysListView32 controls and I'll have to get the data of a specific SysListView32 control, but the only thing that I can use to get this specific control is the column's header (SysHeader32) text, they are different for each SysListView32 control.

I got capture the data (all texts from rows and columns) from the all SysListView32 controls, but I can't capture the text of header columns.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Show us the work that you done and ask for help when you are struck.

Comment: I'm using pinvoke, I got the data from each ListView's item using the code from this site: http://konradn.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/read-listviewitem-content-from-another-process/. To get the text from header column, I'm trying to navigate for all child window of SysHeader32 controls and for each one I use "static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount)" trying to get the text, but It returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to send the control a [`LVM_GETCOLUMN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774911.aspx) message. The difficulty is that the message fills the contents of a struct that is passed as a pointer to the struct. But that pointer must refer to memory allocated in the process which owns the list view. In your scenario the list view is owned by a different process.

You can work around this by using `VirtualAlloc` to allocate memory in the other processes. You can then initialize that memory with `WriteProcessMemory`. Then send the message before reading the contents using `ReadProcessMemory`. Finally, deallocate with `VirtualFree`.

This is quite a fiddle to get right, and it's even more complicated if the target process is a different bitness.

Having seen your comment to the question, it's clear that you are already familiar with this technique.

In my opinion, you may well be better off using the automation API, which I believe will give you the information much more readily.

Comment: The code from the site: http://konradn.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/read-listviewitem-content-from-another-process/, already uses VirtualAlloc, WriteProcessMemory, ReadProcessMemory and VirtualFree.

Comment: That's fine. When I wrote my answer, you had not made it clear that you were using that technique. Indeed the question still makes no mention of it. If you think that's important information, add it to the question. That means that you already know the basics and just need to make use of `LVM_GETCOLUMN`.